# What is the syntax for appium's caps? I'm using selenium and rubygems

Tags: mobile, rubygems

I'm trying to run a script I wrote for selenium webdriver using RubyGems to test a mobile app.

I've done testing with websites, but I'm trying to test an app/apk.  Unfortunately I'm not including my desiredCapabilities correctly.

In my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'uri'
require 'appium_lib'

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android
caps['deviceName'] = 'Awesome Fire'
caps['deviceOrientation'] = 'portrait'
caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4'
caps['platformName'] = 'Android'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", :desiredCapabilities => caps)
```

When I run the script I receive the following msg

```
unknown option: {:desiredCapabilities=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:0x66a380 @capabilities={:browser_name=>"android", :version=>"", :platform=>:android, :javascript_enabled=>true, :css_selectors_enabled=>false, :takes_screenshot=>true, :native_events=>false, :rotatable=>true, :firefox_profile=>nil, :proxy=>nil, "deviceName"=>"Awesome Fire", "deviceOrientation"=>"portrait", "platformName"=>"Android"}>} (ArgumentError)
```

I'm sure how I define my caps is the problem, but I'm unable to find the correct syntax online.

Comment: Anybody have an idea on how to use Rubygems or can point me in a direction to find out how to kick off an apk for an android device?  I've tried a few different ways and I haven't been successful.  I'm trying to kick off a android app and test it on a device.  Any direction / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  Here is my sample

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'uri'
require 'appium_lib'
require_relative 'SDK_Navigation'

mySampleApp = SampleApp.new

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android
caps['deviceName'] = 'fegero'
caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
caps['app'] = 'c:\users\myfolder\documents\SampleApp_1046.apk'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
  :remote,
  :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
  :desired_capabilities => caps)

sleep(20)
mySampleApp.PickImagebtn(driver)
```